# How long does it take for police 'presence' to clear when they are alerted?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I engaged with some enemy NPCs, and accidentally shot a civilian in the head (though not sure it would've mattered if I hit them somewhere else or not) as they ran across my screen. As a result of this, I was alerted by the game that the NCPD (the police) were automatically en route to 'investigate', and that I could avoid them by leaving the area and "lying low for a while".

How long does it take for the police to stop searching for me, and is there any kind of visual information on the HUD that alerts me to when NCPD is or is no longer looking for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is visual information on the HUD - it's to the left of the mini map and is represented by badges. The police AI in Cyberpunk 2077 is somewhat poor so the police will not chase you or follow you too far from where you found them. Additionally, police will literally spawn in around where the crime happened.

To avoid the police simply move a couple of blocks away.

Comment: I've since seen this, but it is to the left of my mini map, not to the right.