# How to get friendly with the police again in Cyberpunk 2077?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

Police want to catch me after I accidentally fired a weapon in public. Now, if I meet a police guy standing around he wants to bust me and one blue star appears by the minimap.

How do I end the chase?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "Now, if I meet a police guy standing around"? If you're getting too close, they will do that. Do they do that when they see you independent of how close you are, or are you entering a crime scene or are generally too close like 1 meter) from that cop?

Comment: Yep, if im getting too close. It started after i fired in public.

Comment: That's normal, also happens with Trauma Team.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does it take for police 'presence' to clear when they are alerted?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/379065/how-long-does-it-take-for-police-presence-to-clear-when-they-are-alerted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run away from the scene. The further you go, the faster the blue star disappear.

Comment: Yes, but before the crime I could stand near a cop and nothing happened. I wont to restore this state again.

Comment: @ViktorBe Depends on the cop. Some let you stand close, others start to get aggressive. This is normal.